# Align tikzpicture with textwidth

Tags: tikz-pgf

i have this tikz graphic, but sadly it doesnt align with the textwidth. How can i accomplish that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{startstopnoborder} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
    \centering
    \node (add) [startstop] {Add new columns to the restricted master problem};
    \node (solve1) [startstop, below=of add] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=1$};
    \node (solve2) [startstop, below=of solve1] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=2$};
    \node (dot) [startstopnoborder, below=of solve2] {$\vdots$};
    \node (solven) [startstop, below=of dot] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=\mid I\mid$};
    \node (solvethe) [startstop, left=of solve2,] {Solve the restricted LP master problem and obtain dual cost};
    \node (construct) [startstop, left=of solvethe] {Construct initial restricted master problem with a basic solution / heuristic};
    \node (reduce) [decision, right=of solve2] {Reduce cost $<$ 0};
    \node (lp) [startstop, right=of reduce] {LP relaxation is optimal and find IP solution};
    \node (empty1) [coordinate, right=1cm of solvethe] {};
    \node (empty2) [coordinate, left=1cm of reduce] {};
    
    \draw [arrow] (construct) -- (solvethe);
    \draw [arrow] (add) -| (solvethe);
    \draw [arrow] (reduce) |- node[fill=white,] {Yes} (add);
    \draw [arrow] (reduce) -- node[fill=white,] {No} (lp);
    
    \draw (solvethe) -- (empty1);
    \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solve1);
    \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solve2);
    \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solven);
    
    \draw [arrow] (empty2) -- (reduce);
    \draw (solve1) -| (empty2);
    \draw (solve2) -| (empty2);
    \draw (solven) -| (empty2);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. With the option `landscape` and  modifying the margins in the `geometry` package. You can also add the `showframe` option to see the margins.

Comment: Just keep making things smaller until they fit.  See also the tikzscale package.

Answer (score 0):

A general method is to typeset the graph as a standalone picture (use the document class `standalone`) and to include the picture as
`\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chart.pdf}`.
This will scale the picture accordingly.

Or you design your flowchart smaller, including the use of a smaller font, with an eye to the available space, see below.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\tikzset{
  startstop/.style = {draw, rounded corners, text width=2cm},
  decision/.style = {diamond, draw, text width=1.5cm},
  arrow/.style = {thick,rounded corners,-stealth}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.8cm]\footnotesize
    \centering
    \node (add) [startstop] {Add new columns to the restricted master problem};
    \node (solve1) [startstop, below=of add] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=1$};
    \node (solve2) [startstop, below=of solve1] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=2$};
    \node (solven) [startstop, below=of solve2] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=|I|$};
    \node (solvethe) [startstop, left=of solve2,] {Solve the restricted LP master problem and obtain dual cost};
    \node (construct) [startstop, left=of solvethe] {Construct initial restricted master problem with a basic solution / heuristic};
    \node (reduce) [decision, right=of solve2] {Reduce cost $<$ 0};
    \node (lp) [startstop, right=of reduce] {LP relaxation is optimal and find IP solution};
    
    \draw [arrow] (construct) -- (solvethe);
    \draw [arrow] (add) -| (solvethe);
    \draw [arrow] (reduce) |- node[pos=0.1,above,sloped] {Yes} (add);
    \draw [arrow] (reduce) -- node[above] {No} (lp);
    
    \draw [arrow] (solvethe) -- coordinate(empty1) (solve2);
    \draw [arrow] (solve2) -- coordinate(empty2) (reduce);
    
    \draw [arrow] (solvethe) -| (empty1) |- (solve1);
    \draw [arrow] (solve1) -| (empty2) |- (reduce);
    
    \draw [arrow] (solvethe) -- (empty1) |- (solven);
    \draw [arrow] (solven) -| (empty2) -- (reduce);
    
    \path (solve2) -- node[pos=0.4]{$\vdots$} (solven);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adjustbox`.

Please, note that `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for several years: see the code below for a better method, that also saves from code repetition. Also `arrows` is obsolete and you should load `arrows.meta`.

The package `showframe` is used only to show that the picture is indeed scaled to the text width.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, positioning}

\tikzset{
  startstopnoborder/.style = {
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    text centered,
    text width=3cm
  },
  startstop/.style = {
    startstopnoborder,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black,
  },
  decision/.style = {
    startstopnoborder,
    diamond,
    draw=black,
  },
  arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
    \centering
    \node (add) [startstop] {Add new columns to the restricted master problem};
    \node (solve1) [startstop, below=of add] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=1$};
    \node (solve2) [startstop, below=of solve1] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=2$};
    \node (dot) [startstopnoborder, below=of solve2] {$\vdots$};
    \node (solven) [startstop, below=of dot] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=\mid I\mid$};
    \node (solvethe) [startstop, left=of solve2,] {Solve the restricted LP master problem and obtain dual cost};
    \node (construct) [startstop, left=of solvethe] {Construct initial restricted master problem with a basic solution / heuristic};
    \node (reduce) [decision, right=of solve2] {Reduce cost $<$ 0};
    \node (lp) [startstop, right=of reduce] {LP relaxation is optimal and find IP solution};
    \node (empty1) [coordinate, right=1cm of solvethe] {};
    \node (empty2) [coordinate, left=1cm of reduce] {};
    
    \draw [arrow] (construct) -- (solvethe);
    \draw [arrow] (add) -| (solvethe);
    \draw [arrow] (reduce) |- node[fill=white,] {Yes} (add);
    \draw [arrow] (reduce) -- node[fill=white,] {No} (lp);
    
    \draw (solvethe) -- (empty1);
    \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solve1);
    \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solve2);
    \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solven);
    
    \draw [arrow] (empty2) -- (reduce);
    \draw (solve1) -| (empty2);
    \draw (solve2) -| (empty2);
    \draw (solven) -| (empty2);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are other options if you do not want to use external files, first you can reduce all the tikz code to a single token and you can even take advantage of the fact that you can scale, rotate and reuse the entire drawing, of course to avoid undesired results you must declare the `transform shape` option if you dont do it only the coordinates will be modified and the nodes will remain with the same orientation. As you can see I made 3 options, the two initial options require that you manually see which scale looks best to you, this is quite useful when it comes to fitting the paragraphs together. If on the last sheet you only occupy a small part, by reducing the size of the figure you can make the text remain on the previous sheet, the third simply forces the figure to have the specified width.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{startstopnoborder} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\def\myPic#1#2{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,scale=#1,rotate=#2,transform shape]
        \centering
        
        \node (add) [startstop] {Add new columns to the restricted master problem};
        \node (solve1) [startstop, below=of add] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=1$};
        \node (solve2) [startstop, below=of solve1] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=2$};
        \node (dot) [startstopnoborder, below=of solve2] {$\vdots$};
        \node (solven) [startstop, below=of dot] {Solve subproblem for physician $i=\mid I\mid$};
        \node (solvethe) [startstop, left=of solve2,] {Solve the restricted LP master problem and obtain dual cost};
        \node (construct) [startstop, left=of solvethe] {Construct initial restricted master problem with a basic solution / heuristic};
        \node (reduce) [decision, right=of solve2] {Reduce cost $<$ 0};
        \node (lp) [startstop, right=of reduce] {LP relaxation is optimal and find IP solution};
        \node (empty1) [coordinate, right=1cm of solvethe] {};
        \node (empty2) [coordinate, left=1cm of reduce] {};
        
        \draw [arrow] (construct) -- (solvethe);
        \draw [arrow] (add) -| (solvethe);
        \draw [arrow] (reduce) |- node[fill=white,] {Yes} (add);
        \draw [arrow] (reduce) -- node[fill=white,] {No} (lp);
        
        \draw (solvethe) -- (empty1);
        \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solve1);
        \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solve2);
        \draw [arrow] (empty1) |- (solven);
        
        \draw [arrow] (empty2) -- (reduce);
        \draw (solve1) -| (empty2);
        \draw (solve2) -| (empty2);
        \draw (solven) -| (empty2);         
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \myPic{0.5}{0}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[2]  
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \myPic{0.74}{90}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum[3-4]
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\myPic{1}{0}}
        \caption{Some text}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```